# Can (stable) Germanium nuclei be produced from other elemental nuclei through nuclear transmutation?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Germanium is making a comeback in electronics technology. But there is one problem: it's not that common of a mineral and there may not be enough of it to truly replace silicon(which is extremely abundant). So are there any known nuclear processes(other than stellar nucleosynthesis)which could be used to make synthetic Germanium?

Comment: There are a variety of possible reactions. Could you be more specific on what you want?

Comment: Transmutation is generally messy since you get side reactions and reactions with impurities. Thus the resulting matrix is typically radioactive. Radioactivity in the produced germanium would be deleterious for transistors, so such a production method while feasible isn't practical.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of candidates. Perhaps the simplest is the $^{69}$Ga(n,$\gamma$)$^{70}$Ga neutron absorption process, which then beta decays (half life of 21 minutes) to $^{70}$Ge. The problem is that a second neutron capture leads to $^{71}$Ge, which decays via electron capture to $^{71}$Ga. Fortunately, yet another neutron absorption to $^{72}$Ga leads to another beta decay to $^{72}$Ge.

Other options include $^{69}$Ga($\alpha$,p)$^{72}$Ge and $^{75}$As(p,$\alpha$)$^{72}$Ge.

Note that Ga has about a 10x higher concentration in the crust than either Ge or As, so it might be a place to start. And, $^{69}$Ga is the higher concentration of the two Ga isotopes (69 and 71).

Zn has a higher abundance than Ga (by about 4x), but the isotopes that would be amenable to an ($\alpha$,n) reaction are pretty rare.

Note that in all cases, large scale (tons) production is a useless proposition.

Comment: I think that "tons" is an overestimate of the mass at which this proposition becomes useless. For example, over its thirty-year projected lifetime, the [SNS](http://sns.gov) is projected to produce about a kilogram of free neutrons. If every one of those neutrons were used for your gallium-to-germanium transmutation, that'd make 80 kg of gallium. I'll let you look up the SNS budget and assign a cost to that gallium.

Comment: @rob - for sure! But you would need tons for large scale electronics applications. Now, a spallation source is overkill - the cross sections are much better by orders of magnitude for thermal neutron capture in a reactor environment. The US and the USSR made a whole lot of plutonium via reactor processing...

Comment: I happened to have the SNS lifetime neutron production in my head.  Plutonium is another interesting case because the production process is similar to what you describe, and there are [published estimates of prices](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2008/AndrewMorel.shtml) which are probably also similar.  Of all the things that I could do with five million dollars, a kilogram of transmutation-produced germanium is pretty low on the list.

Comment: @rob - I don't think either the US or the USSR really was concerned about the price...

Comment: There needs to be some serious R&D into boosting the efficiency of nuclear transmutation for industrial scale production of elements that are useful but in short supply. Zinc can be efficiently converted into Palladium in turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done, but due to cost it will *never* be used in manufacturing.